# How to temporarily disable/mute logging using Zap logger in Go

Tags: go, logging, go-zap, structured-logging

How to temporarily disable logging using Zap logger in Go.
I need to mute logs for a particular function without removing logger print statements.
I need a solution similar to what we do for `fmt` as below,

```
temp := os.Stdout
os.Stdout = nil
fmt.Println("Hello")
os.Stdout = temp
fmt.Println("Bye")
```

Comment: basically set up your logger in such a way that you can update the log level at runtime, then in the function that you want to mute, set a log level higher than all other logs. You can also convert an arbitrarily large number, e.g. `zapcore.Level(10000)`